# Class.getResource returns incorrect path in Eclipse and as a standalone exe

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable-jar

I have a Java application for which i read an XML file (`xmlFileName`) from the class path as follows :

```
    URL file = null;
    // Get file from resources folder
    try {
        file = MainPanel.class.getResource("/com/adc/resources/"
                + xmlFileName);

        LoggingSample.getLogger().error(
                "File " + file); --> Debug message

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LoggingSample.getLogger().error("URL parsed " + xmlFileName);
    }
```

I have added a debug message to the above . When i run the application from within eclipse i get the correct localworkspace path and my application launces successfully . However when i create a standalone jar and try running it my path is wrong .  See `log4j` file output .

What am I doing wrong ? Can anyone point out.

```
2015-02-23 18:53:14,990 - Project - ERROR - File Path  /C:/Users/phantom.j/Documents/GitHub/sec-assess/PROJECT/bin/com/adc/resources/MetaProperty.xml
2015-02-23 18:54:26,100 - Project- ERROR - File Path  com/adc/resources/MetaProperty.xml
```

**EDIT** : I put some more debug log messages and see that in case of eclipse i getResource as file:... but while standalone i get rsrc:..  How to make it consistent ?

**EDIT 2** : I think its a problem with the way i package my jar . Which options do you people select when you do Export from within eclipse :

a) Extract required libraries into generated JAR

b) Package required libraries into generated JAR

c) Copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to the generated JAR

Which is the preferred way ?

```
2015-02-23 19:25:16,896 - Project - ERROR - File   file:/C:/Users/phantom.j/Documents/GitHub/sec-assess/PROJECT/bin/com/adc/resources/MetaProperty.xml
2015-02-23 19:26:23,280 - Project - ERROR - File   rsrc:com/adc/resources/MetaProperty.xml
```

Comment: you arent getting any error right. It doesnt say "URL parsed " + xmlFileName). Also I would suggest for not to loose the exception e in the logs.

Comment: @shikjohari nope i dont see any exceptions in the logs.

Comment: There is nothing wrong here. `getResource` is meant to load a file from within the .jar file and that is exactly what it does here. When run in Eclipse, it will simply compile the code to `.class` files, put everything inside the /bin folder and start the application instead of wrapping everything in a .jar file. That's why the path is not relative in that case.

Comment: Show us more code. Are you trying to treat the URL as a file? Resources loaded from a jar are **not** files.

Comment: Actually, it reads a resource from the classpath. Whether it's in a jar or not depends on how the application is deployed and configured.

Answer (score 0):

That should be the correct path *in your classpath*. When run from eclipse, the resource is read from your disc. When you run the jar, it is inside the jar. The problem is, what to do with the URL.

Can you just use `getResourceAsStream()`? Then you don't have to deal with how to open it for reading.

Comment: I would rather say _in your classpath_